# All Masonry items hiding when loading more

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, jquery-masonry

I'm using this code to append more Masonry items to the existing ones.

```
$container.append(data);
$container.masonry('appended').hide();
$container.imagesLoaded( function()
{
    $container.masonry('appended').show();
    $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
});
```

As you can see [here](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/demo/), the whole of `#container` is being hidden, not just the most recently appended items, resulting in a really unpleasant user experience.

How can I modify the script so that only the most recently appended items are hidden until Masonry has had a chance to initialise?